# Is a Lattice always uniformly discrete in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

The following definition of discreteness and uniform discreteness comes from Wikipedia.

A subset $S$ of a metric space $(Y,d)$ is said to be discrete in $Y$, if for all $x\in S$, there exists some $\delta=\delta(x)>0$ such that $d(x,y)>\delta$ for all $y\in S\setminus\{x\}.$

A subset $S$ of a metric space $(Y,d)$ is said to be uniformly discrete in $S$, if there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x,y\in S$, either $x=y$ or $d(x,y)>\delta$.

---

Now, Rick Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces* has the following construction.

Consider the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, and let $w_{1}, w_{2}\in\mathbb{C}$ be linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$, and we fix this pair $w_{1}, w_{2}$. Define the Lattice by $$L:=\mathbb{Z}w_{1}+\mathbb{Z}w_{2}=\{a_{1}w_{1}+a_{2}w_{2}:a_{1},a_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$

Then, the books said:

> The lattice $L$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$, so there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|w|>2\epsilon$ for every non-zero $w\in L$. Fix such an $\epsilon$, and.....(not relevant stuff starts).

Given the context of his sentence, it seems that he is claiming that $L$ is in fact uniformly discrete in $\mathbb{C}$. (Otherwise he cannot fix such $\epsilon$, without fixing the choice of point from the Lattice, and the later proof seems assuming this $\epsilon$ works for everyone)

Is this true? I looked it up online, but did not find any convincing reference.

---

I tried to prove it. So, we write $w_{1}=x_{1}+iy_{1}$ and $w_{2}=x_{2}+iy_{2}$, and we let $x,y\in L$ so that $x=w_{1}a_{1}+w_{2}a_{2}$ and $y=w_{1}b_{1}+w_{2}b_{2}$, where $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Then, the (complex norm) distance between $x$ and $y$ is
\begin{align*}
|x-y|^{2}&=|a_{1}w_{1}+a_{2}w_{2}-b_{1}w_{1}-b_{2}w_{2}|^{2}\\
&=|a_{1}x_{1}+ia_{1}y_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}+ia_{2}y_{2}-b_{1}x_{1}-ib_{1}y_{1}-b_{2}x_{2}-ib_{2}y_{2}|^{2}\\
&=(a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2}-b_{1}x_{1}-b_{2}x_{2})^{2}+(a_{1}y_{1}+a_{2}y_{2}-b_{1}y_{1}-b_{2}y_{2})^{2}\\
&=\Bigg[x_{1}(a_{1}-b_{1})+x_{2}(a_{2}-b_{2})\Bigg]^{2}+\Bigg[y_{1}(a_{1}-b_{1})+y_{2}(a_{2}-b_{2})\Bigg]^{2}\\
&=\Bigg[x_{1}^{2}(a_{1}-b_{1})^{2}+2x_{1}x_{2}(a_{1}-b_{1})(a_{2}-b_{2})+x_{2}^{2}(a_{2}-b_{2})^{2}\Bigg]\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\Bigg[y_{1}^{2}(a_{1}-b_{1})^{2}+2y_{1}y_{2}(a_{1}-b_{1})(a_{2}-b_{2})+y_{2}^{2}(a_{2}-b_{2})^{2}\Bigg]\\
&\geq 2x_{1}x_{2}(a_{1}-b_{1})(a_{2}-b_{2})+2y_{1}y_{2}(a_{1}-b_{1})(a_{2}-b_{2})\\
&=2(a_{1}-b_{1})(a_{2}-b_{2})(y_{1}y_{2}+x_{1}x_{2}).
\end{align*}

What can I do further  I get a lower bound of this expression that does not depend on $a_{1},a_{2}$ and $b_{1},b_{2}$? (so does not depend on $x$ and $y$).

For now, I have not utilized the fact that $a_{i},b_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Well, if we have a perfect scenario that $a_{1}>b_{1}\geq 0$ and $a_{2}>b_{2}\geq 0$, then  $$2(a_{1}-b_{1})(a_{2}-b_{2})(y_{1}y_{2}+x_{1}x_{2})>2\cdot 1\cdot 1(y_{1}y_{2}+x_{1}x_{2}),$$ is the desired bound.

But I am not sure what to do if we are not in this kind of scenario (so I guess this gives us some sort of a counter-example?)

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Okay, I think Rick Miranda actually means discrete. I will explain in the answer I will post on my own. Also, I will also point a proof of why $L$ is discrete, as my above proof cannot be used to prove this either.

Comment: Note that translations are isometries.

Comment: @user10354138 I am sorry.. I don't follow

Comment: Why do you have to work with $x-y$, when it is again an element of $L$ so you can just write $x-y=aw_1+bw_2$?

Comment: If that wasn't the case, you could find a sequence in $L$ not containing, but converging to $0$. Try showing this is not possible.

Comment: @Thorgott Okay, I think I can show this. So consider a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfying $x_{n}\in L$ for all $n$, $x_{n}\neq 0$ for all $n$, but $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then, it means that $$|x_{n}-0|=|\lambda_{1,n}w_{1}+\lambda_{2,n}w_{2}|\rightarrow 0.$$ This forces $\lambda_{1,n},\lambda_{2,n}\rightarrow 0$ (none of $w_{1},w_{2}$ is zero because of linear independence.). But $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete so $0$ should not be a limit point of any sequence, and as $\lambda_{1,n},\lambda_{2,n}\neq 0$ for any $n$, we got a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: That's the idea, but the "This forces" step needs a bit more elaboration. You have not made full use of linear independence yet, just of both being non-zero. If they were linearly independent, you could have both lambdas going to infinity, yet the linear combination going to 0. You need to argue that can't happen. Alternatively, an easier and completely different argument is to just consider the real change of basis from $w_1,w_2$ to the standard basis.

Comment: @Thorgott do you mean that "if they were linearly dependent, you could have both lambdas going to infinity, yet the linear combination going to $0$"? and by the way, why does $L$ being non-discrete imply that we have a sequence in $L$ not containing $0$ but converging to $0$? It is not necessarily true that $0$ must be a limit point even in non-discrete case right?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. The existence of such a sequence would be implied if the claim Miranda makes in the quoted paragraph were false, it is not just implied by being non-discrete (however, it is implied by being non-discrete, closed and an additive subgroup).

Comment: @Thorgott OH okay, I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we find some $d > 0$ such that
$$
|w| \ge  d \text{ for all non-zero $w$ in } L = \mathbb{Z}w_{1}+\mathbb{Z}w_{2}
$$
then
$$
 |w - \tilde w| \ge d > \frac d2 
$$
for all $w \ne \tilde w$ in $L$, i.e. the lattice is uniformly discrete.

In order to find a lower bound $d$ for the distance of lattice points to the origin, one can proceed as follows:  Let $w = kw_1 + l w_2$ with $(k, l) \in \Bbb Z^2$, $(k, l) \ne (0,0)$. If $l = 0$ then $|k| \ge 1$ and
$$
|w| = |k| \cdot |w_1| \ge |w_1| \, .
$$
If $l \ne 0$ then $|l| \ge 1$ and
$$
|w| = |w_1| \cdot \left| k + l \frac{w_2}{w_1}\right|
\ge |w_1| \cdot \left| \operatorname{Im} \left( k + l \frac{w_2}{w_1}\right) \right|\\
= |w_1| \cdot |l| \cdot \left|\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{w_2}{w_1}\right)\right|
\ge |w_1| \cdot \left|\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{w_2}{w_1}\right) \right| \, .
$$
The right-hand side is strictly positive because $w_1, w_2$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$.

This shows that for all non-zero $w$ in $L$
$$
|w| \ge d = |w_1| \cdot \min \left(1,  \left|\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{w_2}{w_1}\right)\right| \right)> 0 \, .
$$

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply! This is a great answer!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let me first quote the whole paragraph of what Rick Miranda wrote:

> The Lattice $L$ is a discrete subset $\mathbb{C}$, so there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|w|>2\epsilon$ for every nonzero $w\in L$. Fix such an $\epsilon$ and fix a point $z_{0}\in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the open disk $D=D(z_{0},\epsilon)$. This choice of $\epsilon$ insures that no two points of $D$ can differ by an element of $L$.

I firstly thought that he was saying something of uniformity. But I think that he basically means this:

The Lattice $L$ is a discrete subset $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, by definition, for any $x\in L$, there exists $\delta=\delta(x)>0$ such that $|x-y|>\delta$ for all $y\in L\setminus\{x\}$. Set $\epsilon:=\frac{\delta(0)}{2}$. Then, $|y|=|0-y|>2\epsilon$ holds for all $y\in L\setminus\{0\}$. Fix a point $z_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$, and and consider the open disc $D(z_{0},\epsilon)$.

---

So, how to show that $L$ is discrete? In the comment, Thorgott has pointed out one way, and I will give a more geometric proof.

Remember that when consider the subset $S$ as a topological space (with the subspace topology) itself, it is discrete if and only if all of its singletons are open, which happens if and only if none of its singleton contain any accumulation points.

Hence, we will show that any singleton of $L$ is open in the subspace topology. In other words, for any $z_{0}\in L$, $$\{z_{0}\}=L\cap U\ \ \text{for some open set}\ \ U\subset\mathbb{C}.$$

The idea is to find a disk $U:=D(z_{0},r)$ centered at $z_{0}$ with a sufficiently small radius $r$, then the intersection of $U$ and $S$ will only contain $z_{0}$. Note that to ensure that no $y\in L\setminus\{z_{0}\}$ belongs to $L\cap D(z_{0},r)$, we only need to set $r$ to be the minimum distance between $z_{0}$ and other points in the lattice. However if $z_{1}$ is another a point in the lattice, then $z_{1}-z_{0}$ is also a lattice. Hence, to determine the minimum distance between $z_{0}$ and other points, it is equivalent to determine the minimum distance between $0$ and other points in this lattice.

But this is easy, the point that is closest  to the origin is one of the initial point, i.e. is either $w_{1}$ or $w_{2}$. So, the minimum distance is $\min\{|w_{1}|,|w_{2}|\}$.

Hence, simply choosing $r=\min\{|w_{1}|,|w_{2}|\}$, and setting $U:=D(z_{0},r)$ finishes the proof.

---

Please feel free to post your proof of either discreteness or uniform discreteness, or counter-example, or comment. Thanks for everyone's help!!!

Comment: It's great that you put this much effort into answering your own question! Your understanding of discreteness vs uniform discreteness in this context is correct. However, the argument at the end is slightly incomplete as the closest distance to the origin need not be realized at one of $w_1,w_2$. Consider an example where $w_1,w_2$ are sufficiently large in norm and form a sufficiently large obtuse angle.

Comment: @Thorgott okay. So, I think the following choice of $r$ will do $$r:=\min(|w_{1}|,|w_{2}|,|w_{1}+w_{2}|).$$ I cannot think of any other special cases.. Oh this is pretty subtle.

Comment: Taking the same picture as above, but replacing $w_1$ with $w_1'=-w_1$, we obtain a case where $w_1-w_2$ is closer to the origin than $w_1',w_2,w_1'+w_2$. If, on the other hand, we replace $w_1$ by $w_1'=w_1/2$, then $2w_1'+w_2$ is closer to the origin than $w_1',w_2,w_1'+w_2$ or $w_1'-w_2$. I haven't checked whether every linear combination can be distance-minimizing in some basis, but there certainly is more work to do.

Comment: @Thorgott You are so right.... Yeah I think Martin R's way and the direction you pointed out in the comment of the post are much more elegant than what I wrote here. Thank you so much for this fruitful discussion!!